# "TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined" While connecting to Athena from React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to connect to AWS Athena and execute a query. I am using athena-express for this. When I try to query I am getting the following error.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'Stream' of undefined

I have checked the IAM Role if it has permissions and even tried with Administrator Role. Still getting the same issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Please find the sample code below

```
const AthenaExpress = require("athena-express"),
aws = require("aws-sdk"),
awsCredentials = {
   region: "us-east-2",
   accessKeyId: "MYKEYHERE",
   secretAccessKey: "MYSECRETHERE"
};

aws.config.update(awsCredentials);

const athenaExpressConfig = {
   aws,
   getStats: true
};

const athenaExpress = new AthenaExpress(athenaExpressConfig);


function Analytics() {

(async () => {
   let query = {
       sql: "select * from test limit 10",
       db: "sampledb",
       getStats: true 
   };

   try {
       let results = await athenaExpress.query(query);
       console.log(results);
   } catch (error) {
       console.log(error);
   }
})();
console.log("I am here")
return(
  <div>
      <h1>This is it</h1>
  </div>
)
}

export default Analytics;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using sample code to test this functionality, however, have you also created the `sampledb` that you're referring to in your code?

There's not a lot of context or information in the question, but best guess would be that you're trying to query something, that is not there.

Comment: Yes., I have created a sampledb and am able to execute the query given in the code through the AWS Console. I have used the same user credentials in my code to connect. Still getting the same Issue.

Comment: Than you'll have to try and find out in which part of the code the error occurs exactly and search in the documentation of the correct library to see why this can occur, and - if necessary - open an issue on the git repository for that library.

Answer (score 0):

You should use pagination property here to resolve this problem:

```
let query = {
 sql: "SELECT 1",
 db: "databasename",
 getStats: true ,
 pagination: number
};
```

You can refer this link to know more about the pagination:

https://github.com/ghdna/athena-express#more-examples